# How/possible to render elements from angular expressions in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, expression, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object of arrays that have element names and attribute values:

```
$scope.dashStuff = {
                        "first name": ['input', 'text' ],
                        "last name": ['input', 'text'],
                        "street number": ['input', 'number'],
                        "street name": ['input', 'text'],
                        "sex": ['input', 'checkbox']
                    }
```

I want to render them using ngRepeat with the following

```
<p ng-repeat="setting in dashStuff"><{{ setting[0] }} type="{{ setting[1] }}"></p>
```

As you might guess, this renders strings not html. I've tried ng-bind, ng-list, and ng-bind-html without luck.

How is it possible to render these strings as html?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact output???

Comment: The output is: <input type="text">

<input type="text">

<input type="checkbox">

<input type="text">

<input type="number">

Comment: You need a directive to build the DOM elements.  I recommend you write a directive that takes the object or two parameters and in it's link function you can build the appropriate element and add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to write a directive to basically do what you want:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vXaaZPRL2KS4SkPkq7kN

JS

```
// Code goes here

angular.module("myApp", []).directive("customInput", function(){
    return {
      restrict:"E",
      scope:{element:"=", type:"="},
      link:function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
        console.log(scope.element,scope.type);
        var domElement = document.createElement(scope.element);
        domElement.type = scope.type;
        iElem.append(domElement);
      }
    }  
  }
);

angular.module("myApp").controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.dashStuff = {
    "first name": ['input', 'text' ],
    "last name": ['input', 'text'],
    "street number": ['input', 'number'],
    "street name": ['input', 'text'],
    "sex": ['input', 'checkbox']
  }

});
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="settings in dashStuff"><custom-input type="settings[1]" element="settings[0]"></custom-input></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I see where you're going with this. However, by scoping inside the directive, it blocks the ctrl $scope data. I think that's why your plunker isn't showing any data?

Comment: Well I didn't attach anything to the ng-model or value of the input so that's why they currently don't show any data.  You're right about the first part that I created an isolate scope which will make it so it doesn't inherit from the controller scope, it's generally good to do this so the directive is re-usable and doesn't depend on the context necessarily.  Can you explain/show what you expected it to show in the data, you can pass through another object to bind to the input using ng-model but you'll have to use $compile so it evaluates the ng-model directive.

Comment: Thanks, ultimately, i want to populate the dom with various inputs/textareas. I'm using ui-router state views to get user settings based on user roles which is defined in separate view controllers. 
So, I do want that reusability but also want to rely on the state view controllers for the form model, so to speak.

Comment: Ah, I was still using a templateUrl expecting it to be there. My bad. This answer is awesome and works! Thank you Shaun!

Comment: No problem glad you got it figured out.